# Python sqlite3 extra character in queries result

Tags: python, sqlite

So I am trying to run a simple query in python using sqlite to try it out . I get the result of the query right, but I get an extra "u" at the beginning of each text field and I am not sure why. Here is the code:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = db.cursor()

c.execute("create table Students (ID INTEGER Primary key AUTOINCREMENT, FN text, LN text);")

c.execute("INSERT into Students (FN,LN) Values ('FirstName','LastName');")

c.execute("Select * from Students")

for i in c:
    print(i)
```

and here is the result I get:

```
(1, u'FirstName', u'LastName')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

any clue why this happens ?
Thanks

Comment: `u'FirstName` is the representation of a unicode string in Python 2.7. Everything is fine.

Comment: This worked without error in Python 3.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python source code, Unicode literals are written as strings prefixed with the `u` or `U` character.

If you don't want that your word became unicode you can encode with `unicode-escape`:

```
>>> s.encode('unicode-escape')
'FirstName'
```